# File Downloading Time Modeling

Tags: distributions, modeling, random-variable, simulation, lognormal-distribution

In my simulation model, I need to consider the time that is spent to download a file as a random variable. What is the best distribution for such a random variable? Is Log-Normal Distribution a good choice?

Comment: Do you have some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given us very little information to build on! Do you have some empirical data to look at? Then start with that ... otherwise, download times cannot be zero or negative, and I would guess some few very long times leads to some heavy-tailed distribution, like the log-normal or Weibull. A [paper you can find here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1783753_Optimizing_Traffic_in_Virtual_and_Real_Space/figures?lo=1) fits a lognormal to some download times data, and the fit looks good.

So maybe if you lack any data, that could be a good choice.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I have no data so this paper is very useful